# Is there a way that I can open the turtle screen midway through the program?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am sort of a noob, and making a project where I need the turtle graphics screen to pop up towards the end of the program(I need to get user input to show what needs to be displayed). I have tried just having the rest of the code first before defining what the setup of the screen is, but the turtle screen never pops up(what I expected). Is there any way that this would work, or does anybody have suggestions on another way to display something like what turtle does? I did

```py
import turtle
```

and then the first part of the code, some input and other stuff, looks like this

```py
while c == 1:
    if a == "just bring me to the composition viewer":
        print("k")
        break
# I did try using a goto(2) command and then putting line = 2 after doing
# def goto(linenum):
    # global line
    # line = linenum 
# over the turtle setup instead of break, but it was the same result
    if a == "+help":
        print()
        words3 = "What would you like help with? press +help again to clos"
        for char in words3:
            time.sleep(0.008)
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        howcanihelp = input("e ")
        if howcanihelp.find("code") == -1:
            codehelp = 1
            while codehelp == 1:
                words4 = "Separate the notes from one another with commas, separate note duration from pitch with a " \
                    "space, note length is determined by how many fit in a measure of 4/4."
    else:
        note_pitch = a.split(", ")
        note_duration = note_pitch[1::2]
        note_pitch = [v for i, v in enumerate(note_pitch) if i % 2 == 0]
        print(note_pitch)
        print(note_duration)
        note_one = [note_pitch[0] + " " + note_duration[0]]
        print(note_one)
        break
```

Then setting up the turtle screen

```py
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Composition viewer")
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=800, height=1000, startx=1100, starty=0)
turtle.speed(0)
```

and it doesn't pop up. After that I have some movement commands and typical turtle commands that work when everything is at the start looks like this:

```py
# setting up turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Composition viewer")
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=800, height=1000, startx=1100, starty=0)
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.hideturtle()

# Variables
line_count = 0
num_of_staffs = 0

# Movement
turtle.pu()
turtle.left(180)
turtle.forward(320)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(450)
turtle.right(90)
line = 1
# line = 1 is so i can do goto(1) later on to get here. It works, so is not a problem

while num_of_staffs <= 12:
   while line_count < 5:
       turtle.pd()
       turtle.forward(640)
       turtle.back(640)
       turtle.pu()
       turtle.right(90)
       turtle.forward(10)
       turtle.left(90)
       line_count += 1
       num_of_staffs += 0.2
   turtle.right(90)
   turtle.forward(20)
   turtle.left(90)
   if line_count == 5:
       line_count = 0
       goto(1)
turtle.pd()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(910)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(640)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(910)
turtle.back(910)
```

Comment: Do you end your code with `turtle.done()` or one its equivalents so that the code doesn't run off the end of the file and close the window?  If so, provide complete code above.

Comment: @cdlane I end it with a ```turtle.exitonclick()```

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is called `textinput()`.

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

answer = screen.textinput("Text Input Popup", "Quit Now?")

if answer is None or answer.lower().startswith('y'):
    print("Goodbye!")
    screen.clear()
    screen.bye()
else:
    print("Return to game!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generally agree with @bashBedlam about using `textinput()` and `numinput()`.  Ignoring that:

The turtle screen won't pop up until you do your first turtle-related command.  You can do all sorts of console input and calculations and when you're ready, invoke something like `screen = turtle.Screen()` to get your turtles crawling.

If this approach isn't working, show your code in your question so we can see where things go wrong.